# Retrieve Firebase Data and Display in ListView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building an Android app and using Firebase as its backend database, however i'm having difficulties to retrieve the data and display them in a `ListView`. I tried few codes but the app is crashing as soon as i display the list activity.

Below is a screenshot of my database and also my code and the error I get when I try to run:

Firebase Database

[image]

```
public class ClientLIstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button clientSelect;
private ListView clientlistView;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_list);

    clientlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    clientlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Clients");


    clientSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectClient);

    clientSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
           list.add(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


}
```

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.javytharanee.quicksolattendance, PID: 6602
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepg.zzb(Unknown Source:93)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepg.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
                  at com.javytharanee.quicksolattendance.ClientLIstActivity$2.onChildAdded(ClientLIstActivity.java:53)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegg.zza(Unknown Source:71)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelk.zzcal(Unknown Source:2)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelq.run(Unknown Source:71)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Client Object Class:

```
public class Client {
String name;
String location;
String latitude;
String longitude;

public Client(String location, String latitude, String longitude) {
    this.location = location;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public Map toMap() {
    Map client = new HashMap();

    client.put("Name", this.name);
    client.put("Location", this.location);
    client.put("Latitude", this.latitude);
    client.put("Longitude", this.longitude);

    return client;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error, because you are missing a child. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
```

to

```
String value = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
```

The output in your logat will be the name of all clients.

**P.S.** Also be aware that you'll encounter other errors in your project because the name of your fields inside your `Client` class are all lowercase while in your database all start with a capital letter. The name should be the same. Please also take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724519/how-to-retrieve-value-in-recyclerview-i-tried-a-lot-but-it-retrieve-a-null-value/49748324)**.

```
public class Client {
    private String name, location, latitude, longitude;

    public Client() {}

    public Client(String name, String location, String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getLocation() { return location; }
    public String getLatitude() { return latitude; }
    public String getLongitude() { return longitude; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer yet again but it doesn't display anything even after changing the fields name to Capital. It just shows the search and the button

Comment: Because of the getters. You should keep your class as it is and delete the old data from your database and add fresh one. Does it work this way?

Comment: Please also see how your model class should look in my updated answer.

Comment: I tried deleting data and adding new ones but no luck. If i change my class to this one i get errors in other classes

Comment: How does it show your database with the new data? What are the errors that you get? Which are other classes?

Comment: I don't get any errors its just it doesn't display anything on the app, i have another createClient class where it creates the client

Comment: Is there any other way i can get in contact with you

Comment: If you have add new data and all your fields are in your database with lowercase, then you should also change this line `String value = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);` with `String value = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);`, right?

Comment: I left it as upper case but still no data in the app

Comment: I managed to retrieve them but i have to click on the search bar first and then close the keyboard for them to appear @Alex Mamo

Comment: It doesn't appear straight away, i have to click on the search bar first and then close it for it to appear. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: @JakeQuinter So you managed to display the data from the database. Now, do you think that my answers helped you solve the issues? If yes, please consider accepting both answers. Thanks!

Comment: I did but like i said after clicking the search bar and then closing it for me to see them, not like what i wanted but i can accept your answer

Comment: @JakeQuinter Thank you. If something else comes up, post another question so me and other users can help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

create `POJO` class `ArrayList` and add this in your list check below code

```
    public class ClientLIstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button clientSelect;
private ListView clientlistView;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private ArrayList<Client> list = new ArrayList>(); // 1=change here
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_list);

    clientlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientListView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    clientlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Clients");


    clientSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectClient);

    clientSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           Client value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Client.class);  // 2=change here
           list.add(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Error here: adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);